# Recursive addition in Prolog

Tags: recursion, prolog, addition, successor-arithmetics

**Knowledge Base**

```
add(0,Y,Y). // clause 1
add(succ(X),Y,succ(Z)) :- add(X,Y,Z). // clause 2
```

**Query**

```
add(succ(succ(succ(0))), succ(succ(0)), R)
```

**Trace**

```
Call: (6) add(succ(succ(succ(0))), succ(succ(0)), R)
Call: (7) add(succ(succ(0)), succ(succ(0)), _G648)
Call: (8) add(succ(0), succ(succ(0)), _G650)
Call: (9) add(0, succ(succ(0)), _G652)
Exit: (9) add(0, succ(succ(0)), succ(succ(0)))
Exit: (8) add(succ(0), succ(succ(0)), succ(succ(succ(0))))
Exit: (7) add(succ(succ(0)), succ(succ(0)), succ(succ(succ(succ(0)))))
Exit: (6) add(succ(succ(succ(0))), succ(succ(0)), succ(succ(succ(succ(succ(0))))))
```

**My Question**

- I see how the recursive call in clause 2 strips the outermost succ()
  at each call for argument 1.
- I see how it adds an outer succ() to argument 3 at each call.
- I see when the 1st argument as a result of these recursive calls
  reaches 0.  At that point, I see how the 1st clause copies the 2nd
  argument to the 3rd argument.

*This is where I get confused.*

1. Once the 1st clause is executed, does the 2nd clause automatically
   get executed as well, then adding succ() to the first argument?
2. Also, how does the program terminate, and why doesn't it just keep
   adding succ() to the first and 3rd arguments infinitely?

> **Explanation from LearnPrologNow.com (which I don't understand)**
>
> Let’s go step by step through the way Prolog processes this query. The
>   trace and search tree for the query are given below.
>
> The first argument is not 0 , which means that only the second clause
>   for add/3 can be used. This leads to a recursive call of add/3 . The
>   outermost succ functor is stripped off the first argument of the
>   original query, and the result becomes the first argument of the
>   recursive query. The second argument is passed on unchanged to the
>   recursive query, and the third argument of the recursive query is a
>   variable, the internal variable _G648 in the trace given below. Note
>   that _G648 is not instantiated yet. However it shares values with R
>   (the variable that we used as the third argument in the original
>   query) because R was instantiated to succ(_G648) when the query was
>   unified with the head of the second clause. But that means that R is
>   not a completely uninstantiated variable anymore. It is now a complex
>   term, that has a (uninstantiated) variable as its argument.
>
> The next two steps are essentially the same. With every step the first
>   argument becomes one layer of succ smaller; both the trace and the
>   search tree given below show this nicely. At the same time, a succ
>   functor is added to R at every step, but always leaving the innermost
>   variable uninstantiated. After the first recursive call R is
>   succ(_G648) . After the second recursive call, _G648 is instantiated
>   with succ(_G650) , so that R is succ(succ(_G650) . After the third
>   recursive call, _G650 is instantiated with succ(_G652) and R therefore
>   becomes succ(succ(succ(_G652))) . The search tree shows this step by
>   step instantiation.
>
> At this stage all succ functors have been stripped off the first
>   argument and we can apply the base clause. The third argument is
>   equated with the second argument, so the ‘hole’ (the uninstantiated
>   variable) in the complex term R is finally filled, and we are through.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let us start by getting the **terminology** right.

These are the **clauses**, as you correctly indicate:

```
add(0, Y, Y).
add(succ(X), Y, succ(Z)) :- add(X, Y, Z).
```

Let us first read this program *declaratively*, just to make sure we understand its meaning correctly:

1. `0` plus `Y` is `Y`. This makes sense.
2. **If** it is true that `X` plus `Y` is `Z` **then** it is true that the successor of `X` plus `Y` is the successor of `Z`.

This is a good way to read this definition, because it is sufficiently general to cover various modes of use. For example, let us start with the **most general query**, where all arguments are fresh variables:

```
?- add(X, Y, Z).
X = 0,
Y = Z ;
X = succ(0),
Z = succ(Y) ;
X = succ(succ(0)),
Z = succ(succ(Y)) .
```

In this case, there is **nothing to "strip"**, since none of the arguments is instantiated. Yet, Prolog still reports very sensible answers that make clear for which terms the relation **holds**.

In your case, you are considering a different **query** (not a "predicate definition"!), namely the *query*:

```
?- add(succ(succ(succ(0))), succ(succ(0)), R).
R = succ(succ(succ(succ(succ(0))))).
```

This is simply a **special case** of the more general query shown above, and a natural **consequence** of your program.

We can also go in the other direction and *generalize* this query. For example, this is a *generalization*, because we replace one *ground* argument by a logical **variable**:

```
?- add(succ(succ(succ(0))), B, R).
R = succ(succ(succ(B))).
```

If you follow the explanation you posted, you will make your life very difficult, and arrive at a very limited view of logic programs: Realistically, you will only be able to trace a tiny fragment of modes in which you *could* use your predicates, and a procedural reading thus falls quite short of what you are *actually* describing.

If you really insist on a procedural reading, start with a *simpler case* first. For example, let us consider:

```
?- add(succ(0), succ(0), R).
```

To "step through" procedurally, we can proceed as follows:

1. Does the first clause *match*? (Note that "matching" is already limited reading: Prolog actually applies **unification**, and a procedural reading leads us away from this generality.)
2. Answer: **No**, because `s(_)` does not unify with `0`. So only the second clause applies.
3. The second clause only holds **if** its body holds, and in this case **if** `add(0, succ(0), Z)` holds. And *this* holds (by applying the *first clause*) **if** `Z` is `succ(0)` and `R` is `succ(Z)`.
4. Therefore, *one answer*  is `R = succ(succ(0)).`. This answer is **reported**.
5. Are there *other solutions*? These are only reported **on backtracking**.
6. Answer: **No**, there are no other solutions, because no further clause matches.

I leave it as an exercise to apply this painstaking method to the more complex query shown in the book. It is straight-forward to do it, but will increasingly lead you away from the most valuable aspects of logic programs, found in their **generality** and elegant declarative expression.

Your question regarding **termination** is both subtle and insightful. Note that we must distinguish between *existential* and *universal* termination in Prolog.

For example, consider again the **most general query** shown above: It yields answers, but it **does not terminate**. For an answer to be reported, it is enough that an answer substitution is found that makes the query **true**. This is the case in your example. Alternatives, if any potentially remain, are tried and reported on backtracking.

You can always try the following to test *termination* of your query: Simply append `false/0`, for example:

```
?- add(X, Y, Z), false.
nontermination
```

This lets you focus on termination properties without caring about concrete answers.

Note also that `add/3` is a terrible name for a relation: An imperative always implies a *direction*, but this is in fact much more *general* and usable also if none of the arguments are even instantiated! A good predicate name should reflect this generality.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer my question and for giving a better explanation than this book.

Comment: You are very welcome! As I see it, a major attraction of Prolog is that we *don't* have to trace it in such a painful way to debug our programs. Instead, we can apply much more powerful debugging methods based on declarative properties of our programs, and very quickly narrow down mistakes in our code simply by applying logical reasoning. Tracing will only lead you away from the true power and generality of the language, by forcing you to read your code in a particular direction of use. Please see my profile page for resources that I hope help you with learning Prolog. Enjoy!

Comment: Maybe one of my biggest problems is coming from purely an procedural programming background.  I saw the links in your profile and I'm wondering why they don't rank higher in Google than LearnPrologNow :D

Comment: Thank you. Most of this is very new, so let's see how the Google rank develops over time.